# Convert hh:mm:ss:mm to hh:mm:ss

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written a code that subtracts 2 DateTime properties and gives AHT for that task. AHT shows as follows 00:00:00:567, but how can display this as hh:mm:ss format.

Kindly help with this, help is very much appreciated

Below is my Action created.

```
using(Db db = new Db())
            {
                Chat newDTO = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatId == id).FirstOrDefault();

                DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(newDTO.FeedbackDateTime);
                DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime(newDTO.FeedbackSharedDateTime);
                TimeSpan duration = endtime.Subtract(startTime);
                //hh:mm:ss

                string stringAHT = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}",
                        24 * duration.Days + duration.Hours,
                        duration.Minutes,
                        duration.Seconds,
                        duration.Milliseconds
                        );

                newDTO.AuditorAHT = stringAHT;
                

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With that code, it looks to me that the duration between `startTime` and `endTime` is in fact less than 1 second.  What are the values that you're looking at, because to answer the question - which is to output the time in `HH:mm:ss` format instead of `HH:mm:ss:fff` (which is currently what you're doing) is to remove the `duration.Milliseconds` from the output string.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Removing duration.Milliseconds does not save any input. example for currently it shows 00:00:00:467, removing duration.Milliseconds will show as 00:00:00. What I am looking for is that how to keep it simple to show hh:mm:ss. Thank you again

Comment: Just remove the `duration.Milliseconds` from the `string.Format` call.  Am I missing something here?  You are **explicitly** formatting the string, including the milliseconds.  If you don't want them - don't include them

Comment: Removed duration.Milliseconds, shows as 00:00:00 :(

Comment: Yeah - because the timespan between `startTime` and `endtime` is less than 1 second.  Using the debugger, what are the values of `startTime` and `endtime`?

Comment: That's true,  how can I simply show AHT as hh:mm:ss an not hh:mm:ss:ms

Comment: We're going around in circles here.  You want to show `HH:mm:ss`.  To do that, you remove the `duration.Milliseconds` from your format string in your code.  The fact that your `duration` is less than 1 second means that the output string is going to be `00:00:00`.  If your duration was 1.2 seconds, you will get `00:00:01` (because you are ignoring the milliseconds portion of the duration).  If you want more help on this, what are the values of `startTime`, `endtime` and `duration`?

Comment: Hi @Riyaz Shaikh,The previous comments said are correct,just remove the `duration.Milliseconds`.Your example is 00:00:00.467,so `00:00:00` is the correct result for your expecred format.

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh,change your code like below:`string stringAHT = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",24 * duration.Days + duration.Hours,duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds);`.Just remove `duration.Milliseconds` and `:{3:D2}`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen startTime = 2021-02-17 12:35:56.577, endTime= 2021-02-17 12:35:56.593 and duration = 00:00:00:16. Something is not right here. While testing I started a StopWatch with Miliseconds, and on completion when stopped that watch is showed me 00:00:40:590 but in action it only captured 12 ms.

Comment: Hi @RiyazShaikh,if your startTime and endTime is like what you said,the result you get is correct!How did you test the StopWatch?You need share more details.Because your code is absolutely correct.

Comment: Started an audit on WebApp created, immediately went on https://www.estopwatch.net/ and click on stop watch. Stop Watch showed the seconds and ms, I completed the Audit, and when came back the Duration did not match with the stopwatch. :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it work

1. Created `AuditorAht` field as string data type
2. In Controller:

```
string aht = string.Format("0:hh\\:mm\\:ss", dto.datetime1 - dto.datetime2);

dto.AuditorAht  = aht;

db.Savechanges();
```

Now Average Time is storing as hh:mm:ss format as I wanted it to.